# How to put in queue in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I need to send email using  jobs.

First step: I create tables using migrations(tables: jobs and failed_jobs).

Second step: I create class with method hendle using console command:

`php artisan make:job SendForgotPasswordEmail`

Thirt step: in method hendle() I put

```
Mail::to($this->user)->send(new RefreshPassword($this->user));
```

Fourth step: in my controller:

```
dispatch((new SendForgotPasswordEmail($user))->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(2)));
```

Fifth step:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

My queue.php file:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync'),

'connections' => [

    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],

    'beanstalkd' => [
        'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],

    'sqs' => [
        'driver' => 'sqs',
        'key' => 'your-public-key',
        'secret' => 'your-secret-key',
        'prefix' => 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id',
        'queue' => 'your-queue-name',
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],

    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],

],

'failed' => [
    'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'table' => 'failed_jobs',
],
```

And job:

```
 public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    Mail::to($this->user)->send(new RefreshPassword($this->user));
}
```

Then I sent email. But email sent momently, although in method delay I put 2 minutes. Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and replaced

`dispatch((new SendForgotPasswordEmail($user))->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(2)));`

with

```
Queue::later(120, (new SendForgotPasswordEmail($user)));
```

and it worked

Comment: thank you, but the same problem, and I don't understand why

Comment: the record didn't push in table

Comment: can you show the `queue.php` and `SendForgotPasswordEmail`?

Comment: Yes. I put in the main message

Comment: ok replace the `default` attribute from `env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync')` to `database`. Also, make sure that the `SendForgotPasswordEmail` class implements `ShouldQueue` and uses the traits `InteractsWithQueue` and `DispatchesJobs`

Comment: I'm glad I helped!